# If 9/10 columns match, return the row. How to do that?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to make a query that would return rows when most columns match the query.
The query should ideally be PostgreSQL compatible. (If it was basic enough so I could test it locally in SQLite that would be completely awesome! But it doesn't have to.)

I found a similar thread here but the query was compatible only with Oracle's DB.

Any ideas on how that could be achieved most effectively?

EXAMPLE TABLE:

```
col1|col2|col3
  A |  B |  B 
  Y |  Y |  Y 
  X |  B |  X 
  Y |  B |  B
```

The query would look for columns where col1 = A and col2 = B and col3 = B.

The output I am trying to get:

```
col1|col2|col3
  A |  B |  B 
  Y |  B |  B
```

Create table schema for SQLite

```
CREATE TABLE "t" (
    "col1"  TEXT,
    "col2"  TEXT,
    "col3"  TEXT
);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO 't' (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('A', 'B', 'B'),
('Y', 'B', 'B'),
('X', 'B', 'X'),
('A', 'B', 'X'),
('Y', 'Y', 'Y')
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Please read the first couple of paragraphs in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting the output. Are you looking to `ORDER BY` the number of matches?

Comment: Why do you want the rows `Y |  Y |  Y` and  `X |  B |  X` in the results? They don't satisfy the condition 9/10?

Comment: Yeah sorry, they should not be there. The order is what is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PostgreSQL each condition in the `WHERE` clause can be evaluated as 1 for `TRUE` or 0 for `FALSE`, so you can do this:

```
select * from tablename
where (col1 = 'A')::int + (col2 = 'B')::int + (col3 = 'B')::int +
      ............................................
      >= 9
```

For MySql or SQLite it's even simpler:

```
select * from tablename
where (col1 = 'A') + (col2 = 'B') + (col3 = 'B') +
      ............................................
      >= 9
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it. Create another table with the "correct" values and call it `answer_key`. Then cross join it to your current table.

```
SELECT c.*  
from candidates c cross join answer_key ak
order by (c.ans1=ak.ans1)::int+(c.ans2=ak.ans2)::int+(c.ans3=ak.ans3)::int desc;
```

Here is a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xpGr2MhzFNbF9Lg4ZK7YEu/0